# To find the disabled devices in OSX

Tags: audio

I am discussing about *To record sounds from 3.5 - 3.5 mm audio in Audacity* [here](https://superuser.com/q/788796/2005).

I have connected my iPhone to my Macbook Air (2013 model) by 3.5-3.5 mm cable. 
My Macbook (OSX 10.9.4) cannot find the device.

I see this in my Preferences > Sound

[image]

so there is no port selection for "Line in". 
This is strange.

**How can you list the disabled devices in OSX?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3.5 mm ports on Macbook Airs don't support regular 3.5mm audio in plugs. Their 3.5 mm ports only support "three ring" plugs. [How to use an external microphone with a MacBook Air](http://www.macworld.com/article/1167452/external_mic_macbook_air.html)

The 3.5 mm audio port on Macbook Pros can do regular audio in and audio out. But they default to out and needs to be changed to audio in using the "Use audio port for:" option from the Input tab of the Audio preference pane in System Preferences.

[image: Input tab of Audio preference pane]

More information here: [MacBook and MacBook Pro (13-inch): How to use the combination audio port for an audio input device](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3625)

Comment: This guideline seems to be old. I cannot find the setting **Change the "Use audio for:" menu selection from Sound Output to the Sound Input.** I cannot change it to **Line In/Built-in Input** since there is no selection for it.

Comment: Updated the answer. Originally was just talking about Macbook Pros. Realised you have an Air.

Comment: Which OSX are you using? This is strange that I do not see this **Use audio port for**. It cannot be true that Macbook Air does not have such a feature.

Comment: I found this https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3679138?tstart=0

Comment: I'm running current Mavericks on a 2011 Macbook Pro. But I think the first link at the top of my answer is correct. Macbook Airs only support three ring input jacks. Is the one you are trying a three ring input jack?

Comment: Is the one here in the picture three ring input jack? http://superuser.com/q/788796/2005 If not, can you please, send me a link to the picture what is it.

Comment: See the two black rings around your plug. That is what people are talking about when they say "two ring" or "three ring", so that is a two ring plug. Here an article with an comparison image: http://appleinsider.com/articles/09/02/12/macbook_owners_frustrated_by_new_audio_jacks

Comment: I cannot find those cables in apple.com - only double ring things there http://store.apple.com/us/iphone/iphone-accessories/cables-docks#! Do you have any ideas where to get those triple cables 3.5-3.5 mm? I found only them in dx.com.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't heard of them until I started investigating this question. Amazon seems to sell some. For example http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00JJVPUE2/.